# execution of xml file using bat file

Tags: ant, batch-file

here i have one bat file 
test.bat ->

```
@echo off
echo this is piyush
pause
dir c:\
```

another file is xml(create file .xml) file for creating two text files
my question is that how can i execute xml file in bat file to creating two text file.

Createfile.xml ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="piyush" default="Create_XMLfile">
  <target name="Create_XMLfile">
    <echo file="peak1.xml" message="This is creation of the peak1"/>
    <echo file="peak1.xml" message="This is creation of the peak1"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Comment: wait i m editing the question

Comment: actually i have written my code there too but it' not visible i think so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like an [ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html) build script.

If you have ant installed, you could try `ant -buildfile Createfile.xml`.

Comment: ya its ant build script but my question is that can i call the createfile.xml in bat file means when i run the bat file its automatically call the xml file and peak1.xml is created

Comment: So in your batch script: "ant -buildfile CreateFile.xml"